# Diagnostic app slow down and memory consumption (maybe WCF or MongoDB C# driver)?

Tags: c#, mongodb, performance, wcf, memory

Since about 3 weeks, we encounter a general performance and memory consumption issue in our application.

This issue never occurs before and we don't know how to diagnostic the situation.

This happens 'sometimes', around 1 or 2 times per week and the symptoms are the following:

- All access to the application are slow
- The memory used by the server part is significantly growing
- But if we ask all users to disconnect/shutdown the client part, all is ok again after few (around 10) minutes and users can work again as if nothing has occurred before. So this is not a memory leak.

The technical context is the following:

- Client/server/Mongodb architecture in .net 4.6 C#.
- Client is a WPF app
- Server is a self hosted WCF services running as a Windows Service
- WCF uses net tcp bindings
- MongoDB 3.6 using 2.7 C# driver

As the problem is really general (all services are impacted and all services are accessing to the db), we suspect either WCF or the MongoDB driver to be the cause.

Additional symptoms:

- The CPU used on server part is normal
- The DB does not trace anything particular

**About WCF:**

All client calls are encapsulated in a proxy which ensures that CreateChannel/channel.Close/channel.Abort scheme is always used.

The bindings are:

```
<binding name="tcp" maxReceivedMessageSize="800000000" maxBufferSize="800000000" openTimeout="00:00:10" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" >
  <security mode="None" />
</binding>
```

Behavior (there is around 100/120 client users on the concerned site):

```
<behavior name="defaultServiceBehavior">
  <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="500" maxConcurrentSessions="500" />
</behavior>
```

Implementation for duplex:

```
[ServiceBehavior( InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single )]
```

For single calls:

```
[ServiceBehavior( InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple )]
```

**About MongoDB**:

I've few to say because I've not found anything similar concerning the driver or the DB.

From the server app, we use this option in the connection string: maxPoolSize=500 (and serverStatus indicates we only use 20).

We have a replicaset and an arbiter hosted in separated servers.

OpLog is about 200+ equivalent days in our context.

Log indicates some but very few long running accesses (around 10 per hour but for less than 5 seconds total).

**About anything else**

Our customer indicates there is no firewall or antivirus that could perturb anything.

**Concretely my question is** about finding help or advices from people that has encountered such issues or who could indicate a good approach to setup tools that could lead to a concrete diagnostic.

Thanks.

Comment: Use Microsof's WinDBG, live or from a memory dump. It has a lot of tools to dump the list of .NET objects, size, etc. Here is a recent article for example: https://snede.net/hunting-net-memory-leaks-with-windbg/ or https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/paullou/2011/06/28/debugging-managed-code-memory-leak-with-memory-dump-using-windbg/

Comment: "So this is not a memory leak.". Memory is growing, processor is OK. DB is OK. It sounds like one to me. I agree with Simon, get a dump and analyze the heap. Chances are something is being left behind.

Comment: @JuanR, I understand that. But as we are observing many things since this issue, you know that memory is growing often, depending on what is processed. So memory grow is finally not a significant symptom. What we know is slow down periods are linked to memory grow (not the inverse). Finally, the question is now: what can be a cause to a global (every access from the client side) to these slow down periods.

Comment: @lemon: It sounds to me like you are leaving something behind in memory which is causing the server to run out of RAM. When the server runs out of RAM, it starts using hard drive space as virtual memory and as we all know, disk reads/writes are much **slower**. What percentage of RAM memory does your server utilize during slow periods? I bet you it's close to capacity. Monitor the disk as a slow down occurs. You will most likely see lots of reads and writes too.

Comment: @JuanR. The server has 32GB, MongoDB uses around 20GB, the service app which is slowed uses between 200MB and 600MB. Global used memory is constantly around 24GB. So yes the system could use virtual memory but there is no obvious indicator that this is the problem here. But I will investigate about your suggestion.

Comment: @lemon: I would inspect the processes running as well. There is a good chance that whatever is causing this slowdown (most likely the worker process) changes constantly (increasing memory consumption). Are you able to post a snapshot of the resource monitor during a slowdown?

Comment: @JuanR, thanks. I'll try. The system is in production so this is not always easy to know when this issue occurs. As there is no special alert from the server (OS) point of view. Again the memory usage should be normal most of time but we just know that when the issue occurs there is also more memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

I have no practical experience related to your scenario. As far as I know, PerSession mode can maintain a logical session between a client and a specific service instance. But it is so expensive that each client gets a new instance of a proprietary service when it creates a new proxy.
Throughout the session, the service instance retains memory space to maintain the session state and establish the context state between multiple messages.
Therefore, it is more resource-consuming for the server to use PerSession service as the instance mode of the service.

> [ServiceBehavior( InstanceContextMode =
>   InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode =
>   ConcurrencyMode.Single )]

For your configuration, I don't think it's necessary to use PerSession mode. PerCall services are fine. In PerCall communication, the service instance is automatically released after each service call. Duplex communication also does not require session mode to be turned on. The Nettcpbinding natively supports duplex communication.

Comment: Thanks. But if I read well here https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/sessions-instancing-and-concurrency PerSession is the default and if not in session mode (begin/end), PerSession is considered as PerCall. Am I right? (no sure to fully understand what is written in the documentation, in particular what is meant by 'sessionless' in the table here https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/sessions-instancing-and-concurrency#sessions-interact-with-instancecontext-settings).

Comment: PerCall is the default. I also have some question about the article. anyway, I suggest you make a try and test the actual effect.